# Sorting Custom Post Type Using Select HTML Tag

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type and I want it to be sortable by end users. I have a sample here in this link http://prntscr.com/13camc

How can I do that? And I hope it can be html select tag. Is there a wordpress plugin that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this plugin may help you: [Click here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-write-panel/) . Otherwise you must do this manually: [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where do you want to display this. inside loop, outside, in single-CPT.php or ...... Anyway, the general idea is to do like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">  
<select class="" id=""> 

    <?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'CPT_name',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
            'terms' => array($terms_array) 
            )
            )
        );


    $my_query->query($args);

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

                                                  ?>
                                                <option value="<?php the_ID();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();

?>

</select>
</form>
```

If you are using this in an external file, you should call your Wordpress functions at the beginning like this:

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
require( '../../../../wp-load.php' );


?>
```

Where ../../ is the path to `wp-load` in your installation.

Good luck